# ¿Como insertar datos en una columna que fue creada con alter table?

Tags: sql

soy nuevo con sql, lo extraño es que use el comando alter table para crear una columna llamada "height" cuando inserto su estatura miren lo que paso.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

es un descontrol ese alter table solo crea columnas con null y al insertarle datos se corren.

Comment: No se termina de entender la duda

Comment: La información que ofreces es insuficiente. Por favor agrega los pasos que ejecutaste luego de agregar la columna, que dieron lugar al registro 2. Presumo que trataste de insertar (replicando el nombre) en lugar de editar el registro 1.

Comment: Por favor añade TODOS los pasos. Cómo añadiste la columna, cómo insertaste los datos, cuál era el resultado esperado. Y procura poner esto como texto, no como imagen. Te podemos asegurar que el comando alter table funciona perfecto.

Comment: Por favor, lee [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si lo que quieres es crear una tabla no es necesario que uses ALTER TABLE a menos que quieras modificar una tabla que ya existe.

CREATE TABLE se utiliza para crear una nueva tabla, donde la información se almacena realmente. ALTER TABLE se utiliza para modificar una tabla ya existente.

Ejemplo de cómo usar ALTER TABLE:

```
ALTER TABLE nombre_de_tabla ADD COLUMN nombre_de_columna definicion_de_columna;
```

Entonces, con esto puedes ver que normalmente modificas columnas, y agregarles un nuevo campo por columna a la tabla, otro ejemplo del mundo real:

```
ALTER TABLE empleados ADD age INT(11), name VARCHAR(40);
```

Y si lo que quieres es que no aparezca: NULL, le debes decir NOT NULL al final, para agregar una función a la definición de columna, así:

```
ALTER TABLE empleados ADD age INT(11), name VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL;
```

***UPDATE***

En tu caso, debe ser algo así:

```
ALTER TABLE information ALTER COLUMN height INT(40) NOT NULL;
```

Y para crear una tabla, es así:

```
CREATE TABLE Persons (name VARCHAR(40), age INT(11), height INT(11));
```

Espero haberte ayudado, para más información puedes ir a:
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_create_table.asp

Comment: Siempre es mejor citar fuentes de calidad como la documentación oficial https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/creating-tables.html#:~:text=Use%20a%20CREATE%20TABLE%20statement,column%20values%20vary%20in%20length.

Comment: excelente respuesta amigo, gracias muy bien explicada espero que cuando subas puntos no te ahogue el egocentrismo ........excelente

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que muestras, creo que tienes una confusión en cuanto a instrucciones.

Insertar datos se refiere a insertar filas nuevas a la tabla. Por lo tanto, cada vez que insertes algo se crearán filas nuevas.

Cuando creas una columna, todas las filas existentes tendrán esa columna con el "valor" `NULL` que representa un vacío. Esto solo si no existe un valor default para la columna.

Lo que quieres hacer es actualizar la fila ya existente para cambiar el valor NULL por el valor correcto. Eso se hace con la instrucción `UPDATE`.